# DX11 Unresolved Externals

Tags: visual-studio-2012, directx, directx-11, build-error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Setup, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>BoxDemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory@24 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall BoxApp::BuildFX(void)" (?BuildFX@BoxApp@@AAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Game Institute\DirectX\Chapter 1\Projects\Setup\Debug\Setup.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm using VS2012 and trying to setup DX11 using a sample program from Frank D Lunas DX11 book. I have no idea what this error message means, any help would be appreciated.

---

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Setup, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DCompileFromFile@36 referenced in function _D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile
1>C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Game Institute\DirectX\Chapter 1\Projects\Setup\Debug\Setup.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

Linker cannot find definition of [D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This function is a part of [Effects11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476136.aspx) framework. And you need to link `Effects11.lib` to build this program.

Previously, to develop DirectX apps, you must have been [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) installed. 
Now that stand-alone DirectX SDK concerned legacy and now it is a part of [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx) (since version 8.0). You`ve got it when installed Visual Studio 2012.

The problem is now this SDK version doesn't include Effect11 framework, among other things.

There are several ways to fix this problems:

1. Download and install legacy DirectX SDK. When compiling you will get some warnings, because of conflicting old DirectX SDK and new Windows SDK. To solve this you can switch to your project to `v110xp` toolset or install [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138) and switch to `v100` in project's options.
2. In case of this sample program, Mr. Luna included compiled libs in `Common` folder of source code archive. But I'm not sure if it will work with Win8 SDK.
3. Correct source code and strip out Effect11 stuff. If you just learning DirectX, it is not easy way.

Some more explanation from Chuck Walbourn - MSFT:

- [Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx)
- [Effects for Direct3D 11 Update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/10/24/effects-for-direct3d-11-update.aspx)

Comment: I forgot to mention i'm using Windows 7 if that makes any difference. I've installed the June 2010 SDK, and use the Common folder that Mr. Luna provides and linked everything like mentioned, and this is the result I get.

Comment: I rebuilt both the Effect11 libs, in debug mode I got 'Effects11.lib' so I renamed it to 'Effects11d.lib' and copied them over to the 'common' folder, now I get another error: (see in first post)

Comment: The windows SDK one won't work with Windows 7 people keep forgetting to mention this over and over. Windows is a mess at the moment. They're pushing windows 10 stuff and deprecating windows 7 meanwhile supporting windows 7 for an eternity, making ithard for developers to make decisions. Customers have WIndows 7 so we have to keep supporting it.