# LNK2001 and LNK2019 errors - DirectX unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, directx, linker-errors, lnk2019, lnk2001

I am following along with the book "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX11" by Frank D. Luna. And I am getting these errors when I try and build my project.

```
>BoxDemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CompileFromFileW@44 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall BoxApp::BuildFX(void)" (?BuildFX@BoxApp@@AAEXXZ)
>BoxDemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory@20 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall BoxApp::BuildFX(void)" (?BuildFX@BoxApp@@AAEXXZ)
>BoxDemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DXTraceW@20 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall BoxApp::BuildFX(void)" (?BuildFX@BoxApp@@AAEXXZ)
>d3dApp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DXTraceW@20
>d3dUtil.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DXTraceW@20
>TextureMgr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DXTraceW@20
>d3dApp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3D11CreateDevice@40 referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall D3DApp::InitDirect3D(void)" (?InitDirect3D@D3DApp@@IAE_NXZ)
>d3dUtil.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CreateTextureFromFileW@24 referenced in function "public: static struct ID3D11ShaderResourceView * __cdecl d3dHelper::CreateTexture2DArraySRV(struct ID3D11Device *,struct ID3D11DeviceContext *,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > > > &,enum DXGI_FORMAT,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?CreateTexture2DArraySRV@d3dHelper@@SAPAUID3D11ShaderResourceView@@PAUID3D11Device@@PAUID3D11DeviceContext@@AAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@2@@std@@W4DXGI_FORMAT@@II@Z)
>TextureMgr.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileW@24 referenced in function "public: struct ID3D11ShaderResourceView * __thiscall TextureMgr::CreateTexture(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >)" (?CreateTexture@TextureMgr@@QAEPAUID3D11ShaderResourceView@@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)
```

I had to get the source for the Effects11.lib and rebuild it for VS2013, and I have everything included and linked that I know of. Not sure how to fix these.

Comment: It means you should probably add `d3d11.lib` and `d3dx11.lib` to you Additional Libraries in your project settings.

Comment: Alright well that still leaves the LNK2019 error. The 2nd error I have listed in the original question is the one I still have.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16642989/656243

Answer (score 15):

**RE: D3D11CreateDevice**

You need to add `d3d11.lib` to your link library dependencies. An easy way to do that is to add to your .cpp source:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"d3d11.lib")
```

**RE: D3DX11CompileFromFileW, D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile, D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileW**

D3DX11 is deprecated and is not part of the Windows 8.1 SDK which is built into VS 2013. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

Remove `#include <d3dx11.h>` and `d3dx11.lib` from your link library dependencies.

Add `#include <d3dcompiler.h>` and `d3dcompiler.lib` from your link library dependencies.

Instead of using `D3DX11CompileFromFileW`, use `D3DCompileFromFile`.

The latest version of [Effects 11](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568) has `D3DX11CreateEffectFromFile` which can replace both `D3DX11CompileFromFileW` and `D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory` since that's probably what you are doing there. You can add Effects 11 to your project via NuGet for VS 2013 Win32 desktop apps ([fx11_desktop_2013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fx11_desktop_2013/)).

Instead of `D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile` and `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileW`, use DDSTextureLoader functions `CreateDDSTextureFromFile` or `CreateWICTextureFromFile` from [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) instead. You can add *DirectX Tool Kit* to your project via NuGet for VS 2013 ([directxtk_desktop_2013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/directxtk_desktop_2013/)).

**RE: DXTraceW**

Get the latest `dxerr.cpp` and `dxerr.h` from [this](https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/) post and add them to your project.

***UPDATE***: While D3DX9/D3DX10/D3DX11 are still deprecated and unchanged since June 2010, if you must use them instead of the [alternatives](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/), you can make use of the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) NuGet package. This includes SHA-256 signed versions of those DLLs and a side-by-side deployment license. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but this seems to have caused a lot more errors than it solved. First off I get an error in the HR() function saying 'argument of type "LPVOID" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"'. Then I have a ton of other errors.

Comment: I have no idea what your ``HR`` macro looks like as it's not part of the standard Windows SDK, the legacy DirectX SDK, or dxerr.h. The purpose of this post was to direct you to the modern replacements for legacy DirectX SDK content. It won't fix the fact that the book assumes you are using the legacy DirectX SDK.