# Unresolved External Symbol error, C++ VS15 d3dx9 Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unresolved-external, lnk2001, d3dx

for some reason i've gotten a "**unresolved external symbol**" error and I just can't figure out why..

It complains about "**__snprintf**", "**__sprintf**" and "**__vsnprintf**" even though I am not even using those..

Picture of compiler:

[image]

As you can see I am using d3dx9.lib
and these are my includes & libraries:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "d3d9.h"
#include "d3dx9.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")
```

The only code I use printf in:

```
void v_DrawText(int X, int Y, D3DCOLOR Color, ID3DXFont *font, const char* sText, ...)
{
     char sText_[1024] = "";
     va_list ap;

     if (!sText || *sText == '\0')
        return;

     va_start(ap, sText);
     _snprintf_s(sText_, 1024, 1023, sText, ap);
     va_end(ap);

     RECT Position = { X, Y, X + 500, Y + 50 };
     font->DrawText(NULL, sText_, -1, &Position, DT_LEFT | DT_WORDBREAK, Color);
}
```

I have already tried rebuilding the solution from ground, redownloading the library, adding it to the linker directly.. but no. Just won't work..

Project Configuration (as requested):

[image]

Comment: Show your project configuration please.

Comment: That SDK directory looks very broken with the `%28`. Try changing that to `Program Files (x86)`. If you have the same issues when starting a new project, then you need to fix your SDK installation.

Comment: looks like its not linking against the proper lib. is it linking against the msc++ runtime?

Comment: Yes, it is. @DTSCode

Comment: Does not make any difference. @MicroVirus

Comment: What part of the project configuration? @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Work backward from first principles.  Look in your build log to see the complete link command-line.  Verify that you are indeed linking against a version of the C/C++ runtime that provides these symbols.  Identify the library containing the C runtime.  Use `dumpbin` to verify that the link library for the C runtime contains the symbols.

Comment: Try adding `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` as additional dependency in the linker input settings.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418766/c-unresolved-external-symbol-sprintf-and-sscanf-in-visual-studio-2015/32418900#32418900

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `D3DX9` (and `D3DX10`, `D3DX11`) and the DirectX SDK are all deprecated. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). VS 2010 was the last version officially supported by `D3DX9` with the DirectX SDK (June 2010). In general import libraries should work, but static libraries are quite likely not to work.

> Note that DXERR.LIB does not work with VS 2015 because the CRT has changed. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914309/errors-lnk2001-and-lnk2019/27933578#27933578) for details.

You are still using DirectX SDK 9.0b from Summer 2004 which at the time supported VS .NET 2002 and VS .NET 2003. If you still need to use legacy D3DX9, move to the DirectX SDK (June 2010) release. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/24/10246203.aspx).

Also, you have the include/lib paths incorrectly configured for mixing the legacy DirectX SDK with the Windows 8.x SDK that comes with VS 2012 or later. See the instructions on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for the proper path order which is the *reverse* of what you have currently.